# Variation of fibonacci?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, statistics, big-o, fibonacci

Somewhere I stumbled upon a following method/function. I initially thought it is a recursive fibonacci function, but it is not. Any idea what this function do or what would be its purpose?

```
int recursive(int n)
{
    if (n > 1)
        return (n * recursive(n - 1)) +
               ((n - 1) * recursive(n - 2));
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

UPDATE : Based on comment from @user3386109 : here is the follow-up question : I was suspecting someone might have tried to use it instead of factorial of n, which becomes extremely slow for larger numbers. But even this funcrtion will be slower for larger n as it has a time complexity of O(2^n). You think there can be another way to find something close to factorial of n or exactly the factorial of n which doesn't slow down for larger values of n

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it's something meaningful, and not just, say, a silly recursion example?

Comment: It's closer to a factorial function than a fibonacci function. For large `n`, if you know the exact value of `f(n-1)`, you can approximate `f(n)` with `f(n) = f(n-1) * (n+1)`

Comment: Hmm, interesting, although it's off topic here; try math.stackexchange.com instead. Couple of thoughts. Try computing the output for n = 1, 2, 3, 4, ... and then plug whatever you get into the search function at OEIS.org (Online Encyclopedia of integer sequences). This is what's called a recurrence -- try searching for tools to solve recurrences. Some have explicit solutions, some don't. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: @user3386109 I was suspecting someone might have tried to use it instead of factorial of n, which becomes extremely slow for larger numbers. But even this funcrtion will be slower for larger n as it has  a time complexity of O(2^n). You think there can be another way to find something close to factorial of n or which doesn't slow down for larger values of n

Comment: @Shaggy You are correct. Recursion is a bad choice for this sequence (and for the fibonacci sequence). An iterative solution that stores the last two elements runs in O(n) time, assuming addition and multiplication are O(1). The reason that add and multiply wouldn't be O(1) is because the numbers are so large that f(20) overflows even an unsigned 64-bit variable, so you need arbitrary precision math for `n >= 20`. If you're limited to 64-bits, you could just make a 20 element lookup table, which gives you the answer in O(1) time.

Comment: @user3386109, yeah unfortunately, every time, number being passed to the function is greater than 20

Answer (score 4):

This is [OEIS sequence A000225](https://oeis.org/A000255).

recursive(n) counts the permutations of [1,...,n+1] having no substring [k,k+1].

If you follow the OEIS link, there are various other formulas to get the same answer, as well as other things described by this same set of numbers.

To run your code more quickly, use memoization (just like you would with Fibonacci) so you don't recalculate the same values many many times. You can also iterate forward (i.e. start with f(1) and f(2) and always keep that last 2 in memory when computing the next value until you get to your target).

Here's the forward version (in Ruby; dk Python)

```
def f(n)
  arr = [, 1, 1]
  3.upto(n) do |i|
    # same logic: recursive[i] = (i * recursive(i - 1)) + ((i - 1) * recursive(i - 2));
    arr[i%3] = i * arr[(i-1)%3] + (i-1) *  arr[(i-2)%3]
  end
  return arr[n % 3]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make the function faster there is a an easy way: replace recursive calls by a list of results that you build one by one.

Here is python example:

```
def f(n):
    if n > 1:
        return n * f(n-1) + (n-1) * f(n-2)
    return 1

def fast_f(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    results = [1, 1]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        new_result = i * results[-1] + (i-1) * results[-2]
        results.append(new_result)
    return results[-1]

for i in range(0, 5):
    print('')
    print(f"f({i}) = {f(i)}")
    print(f"fast_f({i}) = {fast_f(i)}")
```

You get:

[image: results fast f]

fast_f has a time complexity of O(N) instead of O(2^N)

**Note 0:** this function grows exponentially. What you expect with N as input is a result with N digits (so for instance if N is 1000, you will get a number made of around 1000 digits...). You will probably have to use big ints.

**Note 1:** If you make multiple calls of f, instead of doing `res_0 = f(x0)` then `res_1 = f(x1)` do: `max_x = max(x0, x1)` then build the list of results up to max_x then extract results for each call: `res_0 = results[x0]; res_1 = results[x1]`. It will be faster.

**Note 2:** It might be possible to express the result in one mathematical expression that is not recursive. If you want to do so, you would need to do something like: [Mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) (it becomes a math problem and it might be impossible to do it). But even if you succeed to get something like: `f(n) = n! + 3*n + 7` (it is an example), the time complexity would still be O(N) because factorial and exponential expressions are O(N).